# Rank Order Voting function returning the wrong output

Tags: javascript

I am building a function that count Rank Order Ballots and returns the winner. The rules of this are that if a candidate has a clear majority then the candidate wins the election.

If not, we remove all reference to that candidate and whichever ballots the candidate go are assigned to whoever came second

So for example if we have this

```
const sample = { "A,B,C": 4, "B,C,A": 3, "C,B,A": 2};
```

Since C has the least number of votes and noone has a majority, all votes C won are then assigned to B, giving B the majority.

This is what I have written:

```
function removeLowestVotedCandidate(ballots) {
    let lowestVotes = Object.entries(ballots).reduce((largestVal, comparison) =>comparison[1] < largestVal[1] ? comparison 
                                    :largestVal)[0]
                                        .split('')[0]
    //remove lowest voted candidate from object
    const newRankedOrderBallots = JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify(ballots)
            .replaceAll(`${lowestVotes}`, '')
            .replaceAll(/(^[,\s]+)/g, '')
    )
    //remove leading commas
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(newRankedOrderBallots).map(([key, value]) => [key.replace(/^,+/,''), value]))
}
// console.log(removeLowestVotedCandidate(sample))

function getRankedChoiceWinner(ballots) {    
    let sum = 0
    let winnerFound = false
    let stretchWin = 0;
    let sumByChar = {};
    let winner = []
    let updatedBallot = ballots
    while(winnerFound === false) {
        //count overall votes
        for(let votes of Object.values(updatedBallot)){
            sum +=votes
        }
        //calculate what is required for a clear majority
        stretchWin = Math.round(sum/2)
        //count votes assigned to each candidate
        for(const[key, val] of Object.entries(updatedBallot)) {
            const char = key[0];
            sumByChar[char] = (sumByChar[char] ?? 0) + val;
        }
        console.log('sumByChar is currently', sumByChar)
        //check if any candidate has a clear majority
        winner = Object.entries(sumByChar)
                        .filter(([, val]) => val >= stretchWin)
                        .map(([keys]) => keys)
        console.log('winner is currently', winner)
        if (winner.length === 1) {
            winnerFound = true
        } else {
            updatedBallot = removeLowestVotedCandidate(updatedBallot)
            console.log('we are inside else', updatedBallot)
        }
    }
    return winner
}
```

However, I seem to be getting the wrong answer, I am getting A as opposed to B. This is what is happening with my console.logs

```
sumByChar is currently { A: 4, B: 3, C: 2 }
winner is currently []
we are inside else { 'A,B,': 4, 'B,,A': 3, 'B,A': 2 }
sumByChar is currently { A: 8, B: 6, C: 4 }
winner is currently []
we are inside else { 'A,,': 4, A: 2 }
sumByChar is currently { A: 12, B: 9, C: 6 }
winner is currently [ 'A' ]
[ 'A' ]
```

It seems sumByChar is not reseting to zero and instead

Comment: When removing, do you want to remove the candidate with the least number of *first-choice* votes? In other words, given `'X,Y,Z': 10`, you only even start looking at Y with that key-value pair after X has been eliminated? Am I understanding the desired logic?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yeah, sounds right. To clarify given `'X,Y,Z': 10, 'Z,Y,X': 8 'Y,Z,X':5` I would remove Y and then have  `'X,Z':10, 'Z,X':8, 'Z,X':5` giving Z the overall win

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues:

- Your `sumByChar` is created outside the loop and mutated inside the loop. Every time there's a new iteration, you add additional values to it. Create the object inside the loop instead, so you get the sum only for the current ballots, not the cumulative sum for all iterations so far.
- Your `sum` variable is also declared outside the loop, and you're adding to it inside the loop. Declare it inside the loop instead.

Also, the input structure is pretty badly designed for something like this. I'd highly recommend restructuring it to make removing candidates easier - using `JSON.stringify` and a regex just to remove something is extremely suspicious.

```js
const sample = {
  "A,B,C": 4,
  "B,C,A": 3,
  "C,B,A": 2
};

function removeLowestVotedCandidate(ballots) {
  let lowestVotes = Object.entries(ballots).reduce((largestVal, comparison) => comparison[1] < largestVal[1] ? comparison :
      largestVal)[0]
    .split('')[0]
  //remove lowest voted candidate from object
  const newRankedOrderBallots = JSON.parse(
    JSON.stringify(ballots)
    .replaceAll(`${lowestVotes}`, '')
    .replaceAll(/(^[,\s]+)/g, '')
  )
  //remove leading commas
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(newRankedOrderBallots).map(([key, value]) => [key.replace(/^,+/, ''), value]))
}
// console.log(removeLowestVotedCandidate(sample))

function getRankedChoiceWinner(ballots) {
  let winnerFound = false
  let stretchWin = 0;
  let winner = []
  let updatedBallot = ballots
  while (winnerFound === false) {
    let sumByChar = {};
    //count overall votes
  let sum = 0
    for (let votes of Object.values(updatedBallot)) {
      sum += votes
    }
    //calculate what is required for a clear majority
    stretchWin = Math.round(sum / 2)
    //count votes assigned to each candidate
    for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(updatedBallot)) {
      const char = key[0];
      sumByChar[char] = (sumByChar[char] ?? 0) + val;
    }
    // console.log('sumByChar is currently', sumByChar)
    //check if any candidate has a clear majority
    winner = Object.entries(sumByChar)
      .filter(([, val]) => val >= stretchWin)
      .map(([keys]) => keys);
    console.log('winner is currently', winner)
    if (winner.length === 1) {
      winnerFound = true
    } else {
      updatedBallot = removeLowestVotedCandidate(updatedBallot)
      // console.log('we are inside else', updatedBallot)
    }
  }
  return winner
}
console.log(getRankedChoiceWinner(sample));
```

Or, refactored to look halfway decent IMO:

```js
const sample = {
  "A,B,C": 4,
  "B,C,A": 3,
  "C,B,A": 2
};

const getRankedChoiceWinner = badBallots => checkOneBallot(restructureBallots(badBallots));
const restructureBallots = badBallots => Object.entries(badBallots)
    .map(([candidatesStr, votes]) => [candidatesStr.split(','), votes]);
const checkOneBallot = (ballots) => {
    const sumVotes = ballots.reduce((a, b) => a + b[1], 0);
    const sumByCandidate = {};
    for (const [candidates, voteCount] of ballots) {
        const candidate = candidates[0];
        sumByCandidate[candidate] = (sumByCandidate[candidate] ?? 0) + voteCount;
    }
    const winningEntry = Object.entries(sumByCandidate).find(([, val]) => val >= sumVotes / 2);
    if (winningEntry) return winningEntry[0][0];
    return removeLowestAndRetry(ballots, sumByCandidate);
};
const removeLowestAndRetry = (ballots, sumByCandidate) => {
    const lowestVal = Math.min(...Object.values(sumByCandidate));
    const lowestCandidateEntry = Object.entries(sumByCandidate).reduce(
        (a, entry) => entry[1] < a[1] ? entry : a,
        ['', Infinity]
    );
    const lowestCandidate = lowestCandidateEntry[0];
    for (const ballot of ballots) {
        ballot[0] = ballot[0].filter(candidate => candidate !== lowestCandidate);
    }
    return checkOneBallot(ballots);
};
console.log(getRankedChoiceWinner(sample));
```